# How to drag and drop Items between two ListView Controls?

Tags: xamarin.forms, touch

There are two listviews, one of them is grouped and other is not. I have to drag items from one list and drop into other. The drag and drop should be visual like item should actually be seen dragging and dropping on the UI. After some search, I found this tutorial [TouchTrackingEffect Demos](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Effects/TouchTrackingEffect/) and thought to apply the same logic to Listview controls. I have somehow managed to apply the touch effects to the ListViews and it is firing events such as pressed, moved and released. I also managed to add items to the grouped listview. However, it is not showing dragging and dropping on the screen. I am assuming, I am doing something wrong but I am new to Xamarin so trying my best to get it working. The attached images show the UI, [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRQyx.png) shows the startup screen, [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0KYO.png) shows the X and Y coordinates in "Moved" effect, and [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXqRe.png) shows "New Word" is added in Grouped ListView on Released event. Below is the code, I would appreciate if someone can help me in this regard.

**Page2Grid.Xaml.cs**

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using TouchTrackingEffect.Models;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
    using TouchTracking;
    using SkiaSharp;
    using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
    namespace TouchTrackingEffect
    {
        [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class Page2Grid : ContentPage
        {

            //public ObservableCollection<GroupedStructureModel> grouped { get; set; }

            ObservableCollection<GroupedStructureModel> grouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedStructureModel>();
            public ObservableCollection<GroupedStructureModel> grouped1 { get { return grouped; } }

            // Drag and Drop Class
            class DragInfo
            {
                public DragInfo(long id, Point pressPoint, AbsoluteLayout absoluteLayout)
                {
                    Id = id;
                    PressPoint = pressPoint;
                    absoluteLayoutID = absoluteLayout;
                }

                public long Id { private set; get; }

                public AbsoluteLayout absoluteLayoutID { set; get; }

                public Point PressPoint { private set; get; }

            }

            // dictionary for ListViews
            Dictionary<ListView, DragInfo> lstStructDragDictionary = new Dictionary<ListView, DragInfo>();

            Dictionary<ListView, DragInfo> lstWordsDragDictionary = new Dictionary<ListView, DragInfo>();


            Random random = new Random();


            public Page2Grid()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                populateRhymeListView();


                // adding effects to ListViews
                // Main List
                TouchEffect touchEffect1 = new TouchEffect();
                touchEffect1.TouchAction += OnTouchEffectAction;
                lstViewMain.Effects.Add(touchEffect1);

                // Word List
                TouchEffect touchEffect2 = new TouchEffect();
                touchEffect2.TouchAction += OnTouchEffectAction;
                lstViewWords.Effects.Add(touchEffect2);
            }


            void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
            {
                lstViewWords = sender as ListView;
                switch (args.Type)
                {
                    case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                        // don't allow a second touch on an already touched boxview
                        if (!lstWordsDragDictionary.ContainsKey(lstViewWords))
                        {
                            lstWordsDragDictionary.Add(lstViewWords, new DragInfo(args.Id, args.Location, absLayout));

                            // set capture property to true
                            TouchEffect toucheffect = (TouchEffect)lstViewWords.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is TouchEffect);
                            toucheffect.Capture = true; 
                        }
                        break;

                    case TouchActionType.Moved:
                        if (lstWordsDragDictionary.ContainsKey(lstViewWords) && lstWordsDragDictionary[lstViewWords].Id == args.Id)
                        {

                            //lstViewMain.TranslateTo
                            headerLbl.Text = " listWords is moved";

                            Rectangle rect = AbsoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(lstViewWords);
                            Point initialLocation = lstWordsDragDictionary[lstViewWords].PressPoint;
                            rect.X += args.Location.X - initialLocation.X;
                            rect.Y += args.Location.Y - initialLocation.Y;
                            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(lstViewWords, rect);
                            headerLbl.Text = "X = " + args.Location.X + " Y = " + args.Location.Y;  
                        }
                        break;

                    case TouchActionType.Released:
                        if (lstWordsDragDictionary.ContainsKey(lstViewWords) && lstWordsDragDictionary[lstViewWords].Id == args.Id)
                        {

                            grouped1.FirstOrDefault().Add(new StructureModel { word = "New Word" }); 
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Create a Grouped ListView from a Rhyme Description
            void populateRhymeListView()
            {
                // defining two lines
                GroupedStructureModel list1Group = new GroupedStructureModel() { LongName = "Line1" };
                GroupedStructureModel list2Group = new GroupedStructureModel() { LongName = "Line2" };
                // words for List 1
                //List<WordList> wordLst1 = new List<WordList>();
                list1Group.Add(new StructureModel { word = "first"});
                // words for List 
                list2Group.Add(new StructureModel { word = "second1" });  
                grouped1.Add(list1Group);
                grouped1.Add(list2Group);
                // binding list itemsource
                lstViewMain.ItemsSource = grouped1;
            }

            async void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3());
            }


        }
    }
```

****Page2Grid.Xaml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="TouchTrackingEffect.Page2Grid">
<ContentPage.Content>
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absLayout">
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<Grid x:Name="gridLayout">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
<ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
<ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Label x:Name="headerLbl" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
<Button x:Name="btnNext" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Next" Clicked="BtnNext_Clicked"></Button>
<!--Main ListView containing structure -->
<ListView x:Name ="lstViewMain" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsGroupingEnabled="true" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding LongName}" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Azure">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell>
<Label x:Name="lblItem" Text="{Binding word}"></Label>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<!--2nd Column-->
<BoxView x:Name="test" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></BoxView>
<!-- Word List Views-->
<ListView x:Name="lstViewWords" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
<ListView.ItemsSource>
<x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
<x:String>Baboon</x:String>
<x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
<x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
<x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
<x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
<x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
<x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
</x:Array>
</ListView.ItemsSource>
</ListView>
</Grid>
</StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: ,If you want to drag and drop listview item between two Listview, I suggest you can take a look:https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/item-drag-and-drop

Comment: Synfusion is not free and I am assuming I have to purchase the license to use it.

Comment: You can follow this link to get free:https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense